# What is the proper test for sparse binomial data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution

#### I'd like to preface this by saying I am a statistics newbie.

I have a single sample from a binomial distribution of some experiment. The exact numbers are:

Yes: 1

No: 45

I'd like to determine (1) the proper hypothesis test and (2) test statistic for whether the true probability of "yes" **is less than 0.05** (not "at most 0.05", if that is different).

## Hypothesis test

It seems I should do a one-tail test. Therefore the hypothesis test is:

$H_{0}: p < 0.05$

$H_{a}: p \geq 0.05$

Is this correct?

## Test statistic

I had considered a Chi-squared goodness of fit test, but one of the underlying assumptions is that the expected frequency for each category is more than 5. If I treat 0.05 as the theoretical probability, then `0.05 * 44=2.2`, which is less than 5 (assuming I'm computing this correctly). I've heard that you can apply Yates correction to Chi-squared but that has its own problems.

So perhaps use an exact one-sided binomial test instead. In this case, can I use the binomial test statistic directly as the probability for my hypothesis test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A properly formed null hypothesis must always contain an $=$-sign (whether as $=, \le$ or $\ge).$ The equality in the null hypothesis provides the null distribution and thus a probability structure for the test.

So you could test $H_0: p \le .05$ against $H_a: p > .05.$
In that case, you would reject $H_0$ if you had surprisingly many Successes.

Your null distribution for the number of Successes is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=46, p=.05).$ The P-value is the probability of getting the observed number $X = 1$ of successes---or more. Specifically, 
$$P(X \ge 1\,|\,p=0.05) = 1 - P(X = 0\,|\, p-.05)\\ = 1 - (.95)^{46} = 0.9055.$$

This can be computed in R statistical software as:

```
1 - dbinom(0, 46, .05)
[1] 0.9055318
1 - .95^45
[1] 0.9005597
```

So you cannot reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance because the P-value is larger than $0.05.$

Perhaps you intended to test $H_0: p \ge .05$ vs. $H_a: p < .05.$ In that case, the P-value is 
$$P(X \le 1 \,|\, p=0.0 5) = 0.3232 > .05.$$ So, again you cannot reject this $H_0$ at the 5% level.

For reference, here is a plot of the PDF of the distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(n = 46, p = 0.05).$ Notice that $\{X = 1\}$ is one of the most likely events for this distribution. So if you observe $X = 1,$ then the value $p = .05$ is consistent with that outcome.

[image]

```
pbinom(1, 46, .05)
[1] 0.3231808
```

*Note:* I was going to discuss a confidence interval for this situation, but I see that @Bjorn (+1) has done that while I have been working on the above (with several interruptions).

Answer (score 1):

For a start, it is clear that you will not be able to reject the null hypothesis that p<0.05, because the point estimate is already <0.05.

You might wish to look at an exact (Clopper-Pearson) confidence interval, which would be (0.0006 to 0.1153) for a two-sided 95% CI and (0.0011 to 0.0990) for a two-sided 90% CI. That shows that you would also (with a test based on the CI excluding 0.05) not be able to reject the inverted null hypothesis (of $H_0:p>0.05$ vs. $H_A:p\leq 0.05$), either, with a one-sided or two-sided level 0.05 test.